# how to make Map ref object available on first modal window render/launch

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, react, arcgis-react

I have a table where when I click on a row of the table, I get the content/objects of the row which I am passing to the Dialog component that uses

react-map-gl

to display the item's location based on the xy coordinate.

```
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

// makeshift data
  const rowData = {
    laty: 5.4959,
    longx: 7.0807,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(mapRef.current); // does not render the map methods/objects on first modal render
    if (mapRef.current) {
      mapRef.current?.setCenter({
        lat: rowData?.laty,
        lng: rowData?.longx,
      });
    }
  }, [rowData]);
```

When clicked it shows the map, but the issue is that the mapref returns null on the first render, when I console.log(mapref) shows null instead of the available mapref objects which I can use such as flyTo(), setCenter() etc. I know it's supposed to show null on the initial render but not when I launch the Modal.

how can I solve this?

Please see sandbox for better context

https://xbzi8r.csb.app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, used useState instead of useRef, and it solved it.

```
const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (dss_rowData && map) {
      map?.setCenter({
        lat: Number(laty),
        lng: Number(longx),
      });
    }
  }, [rowData, map]);

ref={(ref) => setMap(ref)}
```

Answer (score 0):

...just as a little extra clarification for anyone else having the same issue:

```
<Map
    ref={(ref) => setMap(ref)}
    // ... other Map props ...
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although using `setMap` gets you the map, I often couldn't use this map, because it was not fully loaded, I got an error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Style is not done loading
```

In my case, it was better to wait for the map to load. I was using React, MapLibre (Mapbox fork) and wanted to add terrain:

```
  const onMapLoad = useCallback((e: MapLibreEvent) => {
    const map = e.target;
    // Setting up terrain like this is easier than having my own styles.json file/configuration
    const terrainSourceId = "terrain";
    map.addSource(terrainSourceId, {
      type: "raster-dem",
      url: `https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/terrain-rgb/tiles.json?key=${mapTilerKey}`
    });
    map.setTerrain({
      source: terrainSourceId
    });
    map.on("contextmenu", () => {
      console.log("contextmenu clicked");
    });
  }, []);

...

<Map
  onLoad={onMapLoad}
  ...
/>
```